# Terminal Emulator Receiving Bytes from Unknown Source via UART ATmega328p

Tags: c, terminal, avr, uart

I am playing around with a DFRobot Romeo board that has an ATmega328p MCU on it.

I wrote a program to transmit the binary and decimal representation of 4 DIP switches wired as inputs into PORTD (PD2 -> PD5).  UART is wired to PORTD, PD0 (Rx) and PD1 (Tx).

The program works as expected *except* for when the program first runs the terminal emulator I am using on my Mac appears to receive and display the following binary/decimal number: `00000011 3`, then `00000000 0` appears, or whatever number is set by the DIP switches.

If I reset the controller with the UART connection maintained, I get the same result over and over.  The terminal emulator I am using is CoolTerm.  I get the same result even if I flush the buffer before reconnecting.  The same result is occurring if I try another terminal emulator (i.e. Serial, SerialTools).

I reviewed my code, and do not see any obvious errors.  I contacted a peer who says he has seen this behaviour as well, but has no suggestions for a solution other than clearing the terminal buffer.  I have also tried a few different physical configurations such as powering the board by USB only, powering the board from a separate power supply without the USB programming cable connected, and with the USB cable connected.  I get the same results on the Terminal.

Can someone take a look at this and offer a suggestion as to why this behaviour is occurring?

Here is the C code for the program.

```
/* 
    Connection Diagram:

    Serial USART:
    Atmega328p      Romeo Board     FTDI Cable
    PD0 ->          D0 ->           Orange          Rx
    PD1 ->          D1 ->           Yellow          Tx
    GND ->          GND ->          Black           Ground

    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Digital I/O:
    Atmega328p      Romeo Board     IO Board Jumper     Component
    PD2 ->          D2 ->           JP2_7               DS1             Dip Switch 1 - MSB
    PD3 ->          D3 ->           JP2_6               DS2             Dip Switch 2
    PD4 ->          D4 ->           JP3_2               DS3             Dip Switch 3
    PD5 ->          D5 ->           JP2_5               DS4             Dip Switch 4 - LSB
*/

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define BAUD 19200
#define DOUBLE_SPEED 0
#define DECIMAL 10

//functions
void initUART(unsigned int baud, unsigned int speed);
void initDIO(void);
void printDec(int sum);
void printByte(uint8_t num);
void printCR(void);
void delay_ms (uint16_t ms);

int main(void)
{
    //initialize UART
    initUART(BAUD, DOUBLE_SPEED);

    //initialize DIO (Digital I/O)
    initDIO();

    //value to be determined
    uint8_t value = 0;

    //previous value
    uint8_t previous = 0;

    while(1)
    { 
        previous = value;

        //Set or Clear LSB
        if((PIND & 0b00100000) == 0)
        {
            value |= (1 << 0);
        }
        else
        {
            value &= ~(1 << 0);
        }

        //Set or Clear 2nd bit
        if((PIND & 0b00010000) == 0)
        {
            value |= (1 << 1);
        }
        else
        {
            value &= ~(1 << 1);
        }

        //Set or Clear 3rd bit
        if((PIND & 0b00001000) == 0)
        {
            value |= (1 << 2);
        }
        else
        {
            value &= ~(1 << 2);
        }

        //Set or Clear MSB
        if((PIND & 0b00000100) == 0)
        {
            value |= (1 << 3);
        }
        else
        {
            value &= ~(1 << 3);
        }

        //if value has changed since previous, print the result
        if(value != previous)
        {
            printByte(value);
            printDec(value);
            printCR();
        }

        //add small delay to loop in attempt to stablize the button state (debounce buttons)
        delay_ms(80);
    }
}

void initUART(unsigned int baud, unsigned int speed)
{
    unsigned int ubrr;

    //double speed is OFF in this lab (it is 0)
    if(speed)
    {
        //double rate mode
        ubrr = F_CPU/8/baud-1;
        //set double speed mode
        UCSR0A = (speed << U2X0);
    }
    else
    {
        //normal rate mode
        ubrr = F_CPU/16/baud-1;
    }

    //set the baud rate
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)(ubrr);

    //enable Tx and Rx pins on MCU
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);

    //set control bits, 8 bit char, 0 stop, no parity
    UCSR0C = (1 <<UCSZ00) | (1 <<UCSZ01);
}

void initDIO(void)
{
    //set inputs for Port B
    //PD2 (D2) DS1
    DDRD &= ~(1 << PD2); 

    //PD3 (D3) DS2
    DDRD &= ~(1 << PD3);

    //PD4 (D4) DS3
    DDRD &= ~(1 << PD4);

    //PD5 (D5) DS4
    DDRD &= ~(1 << PD5);

    //Set PORTD PD2 & PD3 & PD4 & PD5 Pull-Up Resistors
    PORTD |= ((1 << PD2) | (1 << PD3) | (1 << PD4) | (1 << PD5));
}

void printDec(int sum)
{
    //character buffer for integer to string converstion
    char buffer[sizeof(int)*8+1];

    //convert integer to decimal represented string
    itoa(sum, buffer, DECIMAL);

    //transmit character string via UART
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
    {
        // Wait for empty transmit buffer
        while( !(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) ) {};

        //start transmission of character string
        UDR0 = buffer[i];
    }
}

void printByte(uint8_t num)
{
    //transmit binary characters via UART
    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // Wait for empty transmit buffer
        while( !(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) ) {};

        //start transmission of character string.
        //can add character 'O' or integer 48 to statement below, 
        //both result in the correct character being transmitted.
        UDR0 = ((num >> i) & 1) + '0';
    }

    //transmit one white space
    //Wait for empty transmit buffer
    while( !(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) ) {};
    UDR0 = 32;
}

void printCR(void)
{
    //transmit carriage return
    //Wait for empty transmit buffer
    while( !(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) ) {};
    UDR0 = 13;

    //transmit line feed
    //Wait for empty transmit buffer
    while( !(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) ) {};
    UDR0 = 10;
}

void delay_ms (uint16_t ms) 
{
    uint16_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < ms; i++)
        _delay_ms(1);
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what I see on the program first scan.

[image: CoolTerm display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is not enough time between enabling the weak pull-ups and the first sampling.

Try to put a delay before the loop!

Comment: Hmmm that makes sense... let me try that